# How to place background image behind page content?

Tags: html, css

I've got a background image on my webpage. Now I want to add content that floats over it. The code below places the content behind the image. How to correct it?

Note that I've borrowed (and I'm trying to get the effect) discussed in this link for background image:  `CSS-Only Technique #2` from: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #bg {
            position: fixed; 
            top: -50%; 
            left: -50%; 
            width: 200%; 
            height: 200%;
          }
          #bg img {
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            left: 0; 
            right: 0; 
            bottom: 0; 
            margin: auto; 
            min-width: 50%;
            min-height: 50%;
          }
     -->
     </style>      
</head> 
<body>

    <div id="bg">
        <img src="myimage.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="mycontent">
        ...
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put the background image on the body instead

Comment: I would suggest putting the background image on the body tag. If not, try giving #bg a z-index of -1 or something, or you could even put your #bg div last and the content first.

Comment: div with bg class not required, you can add background image to mycontent div

Comment: @jleggio, Adding `z-index: -1;` to `#bg` seems to work, but any idea on browser compatibility?

Comment: @user46688 Works across all browsers and IE 4+

Comment: @jleggio, add as answer and i'll accept (seems the easiest solution). Putting #bg div last didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set your `z-index` to a negative value

```
#bg{
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been my goto solution for easy BG images.
You wont need to add the image the the HTML markup - just reference in the css file.
This will also perfectly scale the image for you.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Source:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image

Comment: Only works for IE 9+ (that's why I went with `CSS-only Technique #2` in that link). But, I'm willing to do that if there's no other solution...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this:

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093955/make-the-image-go-behind-the-text-and-keep-it-in-center-using-css)

[Reference 4](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Background-Image-in-HTML)